# Why doesn't remote debugging work for WCF service hosted by IIS?

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, iis

I have a simple WCF service hosted by IIS and am running into the classic problem of not being able to load symbols or hit a breakpoint when remotely debugging, although I believe I am doing everything correctly.  Here is a simple sequence of screen snapshots of the steps I'm following; could someone with a sharp eye please point out what I'm missing?

1. The dll for the app rests in the indicated directory here, with its own app pool as shown:[image]
2. And that folder, containing the dll and pdb for debugging info, looks like this:

[image]

3. I start the Visual Studio remote debugging monitor (as an admin) on the remote machine:

[image]

4. On my local machine, where my code exists, I go to Tools | Attach To Process, and navigate to the remote machine, and pick the w3wp.exe process for the service pool hosting my application:

[image]

5. Back on the remote machine, the VS debugging monitor shows I'm connected:

[image]

6. But on my local machine, no debugging information is available.  And yes, I am absolutely positive the code that has been built locally was a debug build and exactly matches what was moved to the remote machine:

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot #4, Attach to Process, I spotted "Attach to: Automatic (Native Code)" in the top line. Try setting it manually to "Managed".

Comment: NODOTS, thank you, that was the answer!  I selected "Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code" and it works like a charm.  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

NODOTS had the answer to the problem in his/her comment.  I'm not sure how to mark that comment as the correct answer and show a screen snapshot, so I'll do that here.

I needed to have "Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code" selected as shown, circled in red, in the following screen snapshot.  Many thanks to NODOTS for the solution.

[image]